# Pthread_t not starting

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I wrote this brief example in order to understand thread programming in C.It was supposed to write "thread 0". But there is no output.
Here is the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

int i=0;
pthread_mutex_t mutex;

void * fonction(){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    printf("thread %d \n",i++);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(){
    pthread_t a;
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex,NULL);
    pthread_create(&a,NULL,fonction,NULL);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Can someone help me ?
Ps : I used this to compile it

```
gcc -pthread test.c -o test
```

Comment: Look up `pthread_join`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Insert `pthread_join(a, NULL)` after `pthread_create()` and before `return EXIT_SUCCESS;` to ensure the child thread is finished before `main()` returns.

Comment: Thanks I've added it to my program and now it's working.Do I have to put pthread_join to avoid synchronisation problem ?

Answer (score 3):

`pthread_join()` is a way but it's not the *only* solution.

If your main thread doesn't (need) to be alive for longer (than the thread it creates), it could simply exit with [`pthread_exit(0)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/).

When a main thread exits using `pthread_exit()` the process stays alive until the *last* thread in the process exits.

This is useful when main thread does initialization/setup and starts multiple threads and then it's not needed anymore.
Otherwise, it'll have to wait for *all* threads to complete (remember that when main() exits, the whole process exits - calling `pthread_exit()` will exit only the main *thread*, not the entire process).