# pipe not working through pthread_t

Tags: c, pthreads, pipe

I'm now trying to send some data through a pipe between two thread (the main thread and a second one) but I get the errno 9 about the file descriptor.
I thought file descriptor were duplicated when thread are involved but it seems it's not the case here.
It would normally return "read from bf hi" but it won't.
Can you help me to resolve this issue ? 
Thanks.
Here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <pthread.h>

pthread_mutex_t mutex;
int tube[2];

void * fonction(){
    if(close(tube[0])==-1){
        perror("close error \n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("son \n");
    if(write(tube[1],"hi",2)<0){
        perror("write error \n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("errno %d \n",errno);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(){
    pthread_t a;
    if(pipe(tube)==-1){
        perror("pipe error \n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    char buffer[2];
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex,NULL);
    close(tube[1]);
    pthread_create(&a,NULL,fonction,&tube[1]);
    pthread_join(a,NULL);
    read(tube[0],buffer,2);
    printf("read from bf %s \n",buffer);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Ps : as timrau suggested here ([Pthread_t not starting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37168752/pthread-t-not-starting/37168858#37168858)) I use pthread_join but I guess it's not the right way to do it

Comment: I guess it's because I use close() but I'm not sure about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought file descriptor were duplicated when thread are involved but it seems it's not the case here.

No, that's not true.

All threads within a process *share* those file descriptors (among other resources). Since, you close the write end of the pipe, your `write()` (done in the thread) fails.

Threads of same process can *directly* communicate with each as they share the address space. For example, you could use a global variable for communication between threads (with appropriate synchronization) or you can `malloc()` some memory and *pass* it to the thread to send data.

The kind of "sharing" you seem to be expecting is used between *processes* created by a common ancestor via `fork()`. When *forking* the file descriptors (among others) are duplicated  and you can one end in each process and communicate through the other end of the pipe. See here for simple examples: [Creating Pipes in C.](http://tldp.org/LDP/lpg/node11.html)